# Obtaining rating percent of the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been stuck with this problem for hours so I need some help. The table will just be named table:

| Restaurant | Review |
| --- | --- |
| Jacks | poor |
| Jacks | good |
| Jacks | average |
| Jacks | good |
| Jacks | good |
| Mapes | poor |
| Mapes | good |
| Mapes | good |
| Mapes | average |

It is needed to get the percentage of good reviews compared to poor reviews, so the final should look like this:

| Restaurant | good_percent | bad_percent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jacks | 0.75 | 0.25 |
| Mapes | 0.67 | 0.33 |

NOTE: Average ratings will not be taken into account for any calculation

I have tried doing subqueries to count the number of bad reviews and good reviews, but can't to figure out how to make work.

This is what I've done so far:

```
SELECT restaurant, count(rating),
        sum(CASE WHEN rating = 'Good' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END 
        )  as good_percent, 
        count(rating) - sum(CASE WHEN rating = 'Good' 
                            THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                            END
                            ) as bad_percent
from test 
where rating = 'Poor'
or rating = 'Good'
group by restaurant;
```

Which the outcome is:

| Restaurant | rating_count | good_percent | bad_percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jacks | 4 | 3 | 1 |
| Mapes | 3 | 2 | 1 |

The problem is I need to divide good_percent/ rating_count and bad_percent/ rating_count to obtain the final table as mentioned above. when dividing it just shows as a 1 and can't seem to work around with round function. Any help will appreciate it.

Comment: Use conditional aggregation. Like `SUM(rating = 'Good') / COUNT(rating)`.

Comment: Oh sorry, just tried new methods and tried to explain it better. Thanks for that

Comment: Just tried that and get this error:
select restaurant, SUM(rating = 'Good') / COUNT(rating)
from test
where rating = 'Good'
or rating = 'Poor'
group by restaurant;

Error:
Msg 102 Level 15 State 1 Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Why are you calling columns that have counts "percents"?

Comment: Missing one step, dividing them for the total amount of good + poor reviews. So Jacks good_percentage should be 3/4 = 0.75.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation, which means that a `case` expression is the argument to an aggregation function:

```
select restaurant, count(*) as num_ratings,
       sum(case when rating = 'Good' then 1 else 0 end) as num_good,
       sum(case when rating = 'Poor' then 1 else 0 end) as num_poor
from test 
where rating in ('Poor', 'Good')
group by restaurant;
```

If you actually wanted ratios, I would suggest using `avg()`:

```
select restaurant, count(*) as num_ratings,
       sum(case when rating = 'Good' then 1 else 0 end) as num_good,
       sum(case when rating = 'Poor' then 1 else 0 end) as num_poor,
       avg(case when rating = 'Good' then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_good,
       avg(case when rating = 'Poor' then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_poor
from test 
where rating in ('Poor', 'Good')
group by restaurant;
```

Note the `1.0`.  SQL Server does integer division and averaging, so this allows the average to have a decimal component.

Comment: thanks! thats exactly what I'm looking for. Just one last question.
If I was to round 2 decimals places how would the syntax look like?
avg(case when rating = 'Good' then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_good,
      avg(case when rating = 'Poor' then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_poor

Comment: @Albert. . . The `avg()` expression would be an argument to `round()`, or `trunc()`, or conversion to a decimal or string.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are already using conditional aggregation, your query is actually very close to what you require.  All you are missing is a divide of the `Good` and `Bad` into the total number of `Good` and `Bad` reviews:

```
select restaurant
      ,count(rating) as Ratings

      ,sum(case when rating = 'Good'
                then 1.0
                else 0.0
                end 
          ) / count(rating)  as good_percent

      ,sum(case when rating = 'Poor' 
                then 1.0
                else 0.0
                end
          ) / count(rating) as bad_percent
from test 
where rating in('Good','Poor')
group by restaurant;
```

Comment: The trouble I'm getting with this method is that there are no decimal places, so the final answer just comes to 0.

Comment: Just add a decimal place to the `case` expressions.  I've edited my answer to include these.